# Want to capture event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In SPA, Everything gets routed using routing mechanism. I just want to listen to an event whenever any part of url changes (Not just the hash but any change )

Following is example of SPA,

```
https://www.google.in/
https://www.google.in/category
```

Now whenever url changes from `https://cherrycrumble.com/` to `https://cherrycrumble.com/en/girls-dresses.html`, I want to capture that event.

I tried,

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",function(event){
    console.log(this); // this gets fired only when hash changes
});
```

Comment: It is only possible if the url change was triggered by the user (e.g. going back with `onpopstate`). You cannot detect programmatical changes or page reloads

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `popstate` ?

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){console.log('url changed')});
```